# Stop/kill a process from the command line after a certain amount of time

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, python, kill

I have a Python code which listens and detects environmental sounds. It is not my project, I found it on web (SoPaRe). With the `./sopare.py -l` command, it starts recording sounds but in infinite loop. When I want to stop it, I have to press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

My purpose is to stop this program automatically after 10 seconds, but when I talked with the author he said that the program does not have a time limiter.

I tried to kill it via `kill PID`, but `PID` changes every time when program runs. How can stop it after a time interval via `bash`?

Alternatively, I can execute this command from python with `os.system()` command.

Comment: Does this help https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process

Comment: Since you want to end the program after a specified amount of time, you can look at `timeout` : https://ss64.com/bash/timeout.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `timeout` from the collection of GNU coreutils (probably installed by default on most Linux systems):

```
timeout 10 ./sopare.py -l
```

See the manual for this utility for further options (`man timeout`). On non-GNU systems, this utility may be installed as `gtimeout` if GNU coreutils is installed at all.

Another alternative, if GNU coreutils is not available, is to start the process in the background and wait for 10 seconds before sending it a termination signal:

```
./sopare.py -l &
sleep 10
kill "$!"
```

`$!` will be the process ID of the most recently started background process, in this case of your Python script.

In case the waiting time is used for other things:

```
./sopare.py -l & pid=$!
# whatever code here, as long as it doesn't change the pid variable
kill "$pid"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
./soapre.py -l
PID=`ps u | awk ' $11 == "./soapre.py" { print $2 }'`
sleep 10
kill $PID
```

I am making an assumption that the `sleep 10` command pause only the bash script while the `soapre.py` is still runing in the background.
Also maybe you the `COMMAND` of `ps u` column has a different value than `"./soapre/py"`.
make your own simple fixes, but this is suppose to work.

Comment: You don't start anything in the background. If you did (using `&`), the PID of that process would be available in `"$!"`.

Comment: I thought `"$!"` will return the PID of the invoking script... good to learn new things. Thanks! (btw i didn't try it with python, but my script is working with a `while(1)` C program)
Also in your solution, you must consider 10 seconds is a lot of time and maybe `$!` value is no longer what you wanted...

Comment: You have `$$` which would be the PID of the current script. Is that what you're thinking of?